# Replace PHP __autoload (deprecated method) to spl_autoload_register

Tags: php, spl-autoload-register

How can I change this code to use new `spl_autoload_register` function instead the   deprecated method `__autoload`?

**My code(works properly):**

```
<?php
require_once(ROOT.DS.'config'.DS.'config.php');

function __autoload($class_name) {
    $lib_path = ROOT.DS.'lib'.DS.strtolower($class_name).'.class.php';
    $controller_path = ROOT.DS.'controller'.DS.str_replace('controller', '', strtolower($class_name)).'.controller.php';
    $model_path = ROOT.DS.'models'.DS.strtolower($class_name).'.php';

    if (file_exists($lib_path)){
        require_once($lib_path);
    }elseif (file_exists($controller_path)){
        require_once($controller_path);
    }elseif (file_exists($model_path)){
        require_once($model_path);
    }else {
        throw new Exception("failed to include class named:".$class_name);
    }

}
```

**I tried to change it to:**

```
<?php
require_once(ROOT.DS.'config'.DS.'config.php');
spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {
    $lib_path = ROOT.DS.'lib'.DS.strtolower($class_name).'.class.php';
    $controller_path = ROOT.DS.'controller'.DS.str_replace('controller', '', strtolower($class_name)).'.controller.php';
    $model_path = ROOT.DS.'models'.DS.strtolower($class_name).'.php';

    if (file_exists($lib_path)){
        require_once($lib_path);
    }elseif (file_exists($controller_path)){
        require_once($controller_path);
    }elseif (file_exists($model_path)){
        require_once($model_path);
    }else {
        throw new Exception("failed to include class named:".$class_name);
    }

});
```

But I'm getting an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Config' not found in /srv/http/mvc/config/config.php:3 Stack trace: #0 /srv/http/mvc/lib/init.php(2): require_once() #1 /srv/http/mvc/webroot/index.php(6): require_once('/srv/http/mvc/l...') #2 {main} thrown in /srv/http/mvc/config/config.php on line 3

Comment: Check closure and how to pass variable to the scope. Anything outside of anonymous function will not be available inside unless you make closure.

Comment: Register the autoloader before requiring the config. It seems the config needs a class to work. Also the autoloader function should not throw an exception, if it doesn't work PHP needs to try using other registered autoloaders and throwing an exception might prevent that.

Comment: i got it thankyou guys